# Can I make an evaluate-once header for bash scripts (like C++ "#pragma once")?

Tags: bash

Is there something like C++ `#pragma once` in bash?

AKA some keyword (or short one-liner), which does this:

```
if [ "$guard_sourcefile" = true ]; then
  return 0
fi
guard_sourcefile=true
```

...but without the need to change each file's version of the header to have a distinct `sourcefile` name.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný Maybe you could do something like hash the absolute path of the script and use a prefix of that hash as the variable name, then you wouldn't have to change the snippet.

Comment: @L3viathan, ...it's tricky to make that efficient, though. Most of the ways to hash a thing in bash involve spinning up a subprocess; if you have a program with functions split up into different libraries, starting a separate copy of `md5sum` when sourcing each library is pretty unfortunate.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný, btw, have you considered putting this code in yet another shell library? It could check `${BASH_SOURCE[1]}` instead of the default `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` to get the name of its caller, and would need to be sure it returns a nonzero exit status when invoked more than once; with those two things done, the call would just be `source runonce.bash || return` -- nice and short. (Actually, I think I like that enough to edit it into my answer).

Comment: Yes, I have, but wasn't sure whether it is necessary. I couldn't find in man pages any better solution and therefore I wrote the question to see, whether am I missing something. Thanks for editing your answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### As A Header

Since comments on the question make it clear that what you really want is something you can reuse without needing to change it to have a distinct name for each file, a *robust* approach would be the following three lines:

```
declare -A already_evaled
[[ ${already_evaled[$BASH_SOURCE]} ]] && return
already_evaled[$BASH_SOURCE]=1
```

...which of course you can compress to just one line with `;`s:

```
declare -A already_evaled=(); [[ ${already_evaled[$BASH_SOURCE]} ]] && return; already_evaled[$BASH_SOURCE]=1
```

Shorter approaches are feasible, but the most obvious ones trade against correctness (assuming that your source file will have a name that is also a valid variable name, or that you'll never source two files with otherwise-identical names from two different directories); it's better put up with the extra verbosity to avoid surprises.

---

#### As A Library Itself

Consider putting the following code into `runonce.bash`. Because it's being used as a library, it's possible to focus on making it correct and readable, with no need to worry about being terse:

```
# Source this from any shell library that should only be evaluated a single time
# Intended usage: ''source runonce.bash || return 0''


# Associative arrays require bash 4.0 or later
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[0-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ required" >&2; return 2;;
esac


# Detect case where we were directly invoked, or called directly from a script
# (instead of a library that script sourced)
(( ${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} > 2 )) || {
  echo "runonce.bash: ERROR: Only source this from other libraries" >&2
  return 2
}


# Prefix variables we leave behind to keep them namespaced
declare -A runonce__already_seen
[[ ${runonce__already_seen[${BASH_SOURCE[1]}]} ]] && return 1

# Set prefix variable seen
runonce__already_seen[${BASH_SOURCE[1]}]=1
return 0
```

...and then, inside any script from which you want to use it:

```
source runonce.bash || return 0
```